# Object literal returning a function instead of value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to return the result of arithmetic expression inside a function, which itself inside of an object literal. The call returns the entire function instead. How could I fix this?

Here's the object:

```
let opertion = {
 'doOperation': {
   1: (num1, num2) => num1 / num2,
   2: (num1, num2) => num1 * num2,
   3: (num1, num2) => num1 - num2,
   4: (num1, num2) => num1 + num2
 }
};
```

Here's the call to the function:

```
     result = opertion.doOperation[2]; //returns (num1, num2) => num1 * num2,
     panel.textContent = result;
```

Comment: well of course it returns the function ... to call a function you use `fn(parameters)`

Comment: Where do you think the function call is happening here? What arguments do you expect the function to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `opertion.doOperation[2]` is a function.

```
result = opertion.doOperation[2](2, 3) // 6
```

would be how you call it